# Пользовательская функция в Python не возвращает переменную

Tags: python

Вот такая функция. Регулярное выражение проверил, все работает. Но функция всегда возвращает none,  хотя при совпадении `re.fullmatch()` должна вернуть правильный email. Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка.

```
import re
def email_user():
  
 reg_mail = re.compile(r"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$")
  while True:
    input_adr = input('Введите ваш email: ')
    if re.fullmatch(reg_mail, input_adr):
      a = input_adr
      break
    else:
      print('Неверный email')
      continue
    return a
  
email = email_user()
print(email)
```

Comment: выровняйте код как положено и заодно посмотрите, где у вас находится return. и в случае ошибки у вас переменной `a` ничего не присваивается.

Comment: `return a` должно быть с таким же отступом, что и `while`, тогда правильно сработает, а сейчас на `return` просто управление не попадает

Comment: @strawdog В случае ошибки цикл просто продолжается, переменная не имеет значения )